# How do you remove a child object from a viewmodel completely in Knockout JS?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following set up:

http://jsfiddle.net/josephbulger/FjmAU/

I have a KOJS view model which has a parent and child relationship. What makes this relationship a little weird, is that the child needs the parent in order to perform one of it's computed functions.

This causes all sorts of issues for me, because when I call a save, and I have to reload all my children, the old children are still having their computed functions being fired whenever the parent's observable is changed.

This is not the behavior I'm going for. What I would like to do, is remove all the children completely before I save, and then add the children back from the server callback. What I mean by this, is that the old children would be completely gone from memory, that they would not fire any of their events any more. However, I don't know how to actually clean them up properly with KOJS. The only thing I know how to do properly at this point is to remove them from the parent's child list.

What is the proper way to dispose of child objects in a KOJS view model completely?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ko function: `ko.removeNode(node)` which calls `ko.cleanNode(node)` and then removes the child from the parent node.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. (http://jsfiddle.net/josephbulger/FjmAU/14/)

Comment: I think you should remove the `self.children()[i].parent = null;` line: http://jsfiddle.net/FjmAU/15/

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I've had to resort to doing this, although I really don't want this to be the solution:

```
function Parent() {
    var self = this;

    self.children = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.troublemaker = ko.observable(5);    

    self.blowaway = function () {

        //i have to do this so i can serialize later
        for (var i = 0; i < self.children().length; i++) {    
            self.children()[i].alive = false;                        
            self.children()[i].parent = null;
        }

        var dataToServer = ko.toJSON(self);

        //save to server

        self.children.removeAll();

        makeChildren();

    }

    function makeChildren(){
        self.children.push(new Child(self));     
        self.children.push(new Child(self));     
        self.children.push(new Child(self));                         
    }     

    makeChildren();

}

var count = 0;

function Child(parent) {

    var self = this;

    self.parent = parent;

    self.alive = true;

    self.something = ko.observable(10 * count);

    count++;

    self.iwillblowup = ko.computed(function () {      
        if (!self.alive)
            return;
        return self.something () * self.parent.troublemaker();
    });        
}

var viewModel = new Parent();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

Notice how the "alive" flag is being used to conditionally leave the computed functions. To me this is just a hack to fix the fundamental problem I'm having.